# How to upload a pdf from iOS device filesystem (not from within project) to server in titanium studio

Tags: ios, iphone, file-upload, filesystems, titanium-mobile

How can I open/access filesystem in iOS device using titanium so that I get a list of all pdf (or any extension) files and select the file , get the path of file and then upload it. (just like in android we can access filesystem)

This is what the official docs have as an answer

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
success:function(event) {
/* success callback fired after media retrieved from gallery */
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
              title:'Success',
              message:'status code ' + this.status
        }).show();
    };
    xhr.open('POST','https://myserver.com/api/uploadAndPost.do');
    xhr.send({
        theImage:event.media,  /* event.media holds blob from gallery */
        username:'foo',
        password:'bar'
      });
}
});
```

but I think it will open up only images .

Also please tell if this is even possible.
And how to add pdf file in iOS simulator from desktop?

I use titanium sdks 3.4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read any type of file using this:

```
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + 'myfile.pdf');
var fileUpload = Titanium.Utils.base64encode(file);
```

And send with:

```
xhr.send({media: fileUpload, userame: 'foo', ... });
```

You could add your files to the Documents directory to your app, this is on iOS on Mac:

```
../youruser/Library/Devices/CoreSimulator/Devices/anyGUIDfromDevice/data/....
```

Comment: But to do this the pdf file has to be present within my application data directory.right? I want to be able to upload pdf present in any location in iPhone not my own data directory

Comment: You are not allowed to use "any" location (like from other Applications).